# How to set the default project for SBT

Tags: scala, build, sbt

Assume I have a build with three projects: A, B and C. If I am currently in the context of A and reload the build, it might change the context to be C after the reload. Because of this, I have to change my project context every time after reloading.

Is there a way to set a specific project as the default context?

Answer (score 9, accepted):

SBT chooses the first lexographical project variable name, so I just set my project name to:

```
val aaaFrontend = PlayProject(
```

Also, there's a projects Seq that I believe you can override.

Finally, in SBT 0.12 you can do it in you .sbtrc:

```
alias boot = ;reload ;project X ;iflast shell
```

Answer (score 3):

Not an exact answer to your question, but you can define an alias which runs both the `reload` and `project A` commands. If you create a `.sbtrc` file in your projects's root directory, then add

```
alias rl = ;reload;project A
```

then you can just type `rl` each time you want to reload.

Comment: A point for effort, but really not what I was looking for. Thanks though :)

Answer (score 2):

The next version of SBT will remember which project you are in and return you there after a reload:

https://github.com/harrah/xsbt/pull/348

Comment: Nice, but when you load a clean image of a build server for each build, this won't solve the issue.

Comment: You could add `project A` to .sbtrc.

Comment: Unfortunately, this doesn't work. I've placed the file in every folder possible and none of them catch on.