# Specifying rootProject in build.sbt

Tags: sbt

In my Build.scala, I have:

```
override def rootProject = Some(frontendProject)
```

I'm trying to convert to the newer build.sbt format, but don't know the equivalent of this line. How do I set the project for sbt to load by default when using build.sbt?

Comment: Show please, what does sbt say. And what is this `rootProject` at all?  May be you just want to set `thisProject := project in file(...)` or `thisProjectRef`?

Comment: rootProject is a concept built-in to sbt in order to specify the project that sbt switches to when it starts up in a multi-project build

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I'm still not sure that I understood you right, but you said about multi-project build, so I assume that you want to define a root project which aggregates subprojects. Here is how you can do that (in your root `build.sbt`):

```
lazy val root = project.in( file(".") ).aggregate(subProject1, subProject2)

lazy val subProject1 = project in file("subProject1")

lazy val subProject2 = project in file("subProject2")
```

See [sbt documentation](http://www.scala-sbt.org/release/docs/Getting-Started/Multi-Project.html) about multi-projects.

Then if you want to set the default project to load on sbt startup to a sub-project, in addition to your answer to this [SO question](https://stackoverflow.com/q/8999804/736957), I can suggest

- run sbt with `sbt "project XXX" shell` command
- or adding this line to your `build.sbt`:

  `onLoad in Global := { Command.process("project XXX", _: State) } compose (onLoad in Global).value`

In both cases sbt first loads the root project and then the subproject.

Comment: The other SO question you pointed me to was one I answered :-) Though I should probably update the answer because I found a much better way of setting the default project to load on sbt startup, which is what I'm referring to here. Except I'm not sure how to make it work in build.sbt

Comment: Oh, sorry, I didn't notice it were you. Ok, so I couldn't find any way to override this `rootProject` in `build.sbt`, but I can suggest two solutions in addition to that yours old one — I'm adding them to my answer.

Answer (score 0):

I've found the following script to be helpful:

```
#!/usr/bin/env bash

exec "sbt" "project mysubproject" "shell"
exit $?
```